# Number of polynomials in a finite commutative ring with n elements of degree d and of degree 2 in $R[x_1,x_2]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let R be a finite commutative ring with n elements.

a) What is the number of polynomials of degree $d$ in $R[x]$?

b) What is the number of polynomials of degree 2 in $R[x_1,x_2]$?

I think for part a, it would be $(n-1)*n^d$ since you have n options for all of the coefficients except the first term which must be nonzero.

I'm unsure of what to do for b

Comment: Small hints: How many terms can you have? Which coefficients are you allowed to have on each?

Comment: @B.Mehta Well that was easy... so just to make sure its $(n-1)*n^2$?

Comment: Write out your argument in more detail - I'm not convinced that's correct.

Comment: For part a), it's OK.

Comment: @B.Mehta for part a or b?  Assuming a is correct, for b I'm just plugging d=2 into the equation

Comment: For b, you have more variables so the solution from a doesn't apply

Comment: @B.Mehta Oh right so There are n-1 options for one of the three terms of degree 2 and n options for the other 2 and n options for the $x_1, x_2,$ and constant terms so we have $n^5*(n-1)*3$, with the $\times3$ being because it could be any of the three degree 2 terms being nonzero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question c), you have two kinds  of coefficients:

- the constant term and those of linear terms, which can be arbitrary. This makes  a contribution of $n^3$,
- the coefficients of the quadratic part in two variable, which has one constraint: they can't all be $0$. Hence there are $n^3-1$ possibility.

Summing up we have $n^3(n^3-1)$ valid sets of coefficients.